# Find the largest lower bound that covers p percent of the data

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

> Suppose that you have a finite set $X\subseteq \mathbb R$, and you want to solve the following constrained optimization problem
>
> Find $\max a$ such that $\frac{|\{ x \in X: x>a \}|}{|X|}\ge p$

where $p$ is the percentage of numbers that you want to be covered. An obvious and extremely brute force and inefficient method would be to inspect every subset of $X$ with size $p|X|$, and find out which one has the biggest minimum. Does anyone know a better algorithm to solve this problem. Even an approximate solution would be fine, as long as it is reasonably well approximated.

Comment: The only subset which matters is the top $p\%$ of $X$. So: sort the numbers, take the top $p\%$, and return the smallest of them.

Comment: Ah of course, how stupid of me not to think of that, thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only subset which matters is the top $p\%$ of $X$. So: sort the numbers, take the top $p\%$, and return the smallest of them. -- [Rahul](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038481/find-the-largest-lower-bound-that-covers-p-percent-of-the-data#comment2116415_1038481)